# Nearest non-negative solution for $Av=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

Let $A$ be a $n\times m$ matrix.  Let us define the system
$$Av=b$$
$$v\geq 0$$

I want to find a solution $v$ of this system that is the closest (euclidean norm) to $v_0$, a given $n$-dimensional vector.

What is the simplest way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What does $v \ge 0$ mean? Is $v^*$ conjugate transpose?

Comment: The elements of the vector are all non-negative. I removed the star.

Comment: You want to solve the problem $\min_v\|v_0-v\|_2$ such that $Av=b$ and $v\geq 0$. If the "way how to solve this" means a tool, Matlab has the function `lsqlin` to do exactly this. Otherwise, these kinds of problems are solved using trust region and interior point methods.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: Here's the full model:\begin{array}{ll}\text{minimize} & \|v-v_0\|_2^2 \\ \text{subject to} & Av=b \\ & v \geq 0\end{array}This is actually a very standard *quadratic program*. Certainly Algebraic Pavel is right, but in fact any quadratic programming engine can handle this readily.